# Get Html response with Retrofit

Tags: retrofit

I'm new to Retrofit. I make a POST request to a website. Website returns response as HTML. So I will parse it. However Retrofit try to parse it as JSON. How can do it?

```
@FormUrlEncoded
@POST("/login.php?action=login")
void postCredentials(@Field("username") String username, 
                     @Field("password") String password);
```

Should I use a callback?﻿

Answer (score 5):

Retrofit uses a `converter` to process responses from endpoints and requests as well. By default, Retrofit uses GsonConverter, which encoded JSON responses to Java objects using the `gson` library. You can override that to supply your own converter when constructing your Retrofit instance.

The interface you need to implement is available [here](https://github.com/square/retrofit/blob/fe6d0f9b2a68063a086fa9da80d04293fbe3becf/retrofit/src/main/java/retrofit/Converter.java) (github.com). Here's a short tutorial as well, although for using Jackson library, many bits are still relevant: [futurestud.io/blog](https://futurestud.io/blog/retrofit-replace-the-integrated-json-converter/)

Also note that the converter works both ways, converting requests and responses. Since you want HTML parsing in one direction only, you may want to use [GsonConverter](https://github.com/square/retrofit/tree/master/retrofit-converters/gson) in your custom converter, to convert outgoing Java objects to JSON, in the `toBody` method.

Answer (score 2):

May be not the best solution but this how i managed to get the source of an html page with retrofit:

MainActivity.java

```
ApiInterface apiService = ApiClient.getClient(context).create(ApiInterface.class);

//Because synchrone in the main thread, i don't respect myself :p
StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);

//Execution of the call
Call<ResponseBody> call = apiService.url();
response = call.execute();

//Decode the response text/html (gzip encoded)
ByteArrayInputStream bais = new ByteArrayInputStream(((ResponseBody)response.body()).bytes());
GZIPInputStream gzis = new GZIPInputStream(bais);
InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(gzis);
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(reader);

String readed;
while ((readed = in.readLine()) != null) {
      System.out.println(readed); //Log the result
}
```

ApiInterface.java

```
@GET("/")
Call<ResponseBody> url();
```

ApiClient.java

```
public static final String BASE_URL = "https://www.google.com";

private static Retrofit retrofit = null;

public static Retrofit getClient(Context context) {
    if (retrofit==null) {

        OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient().newBuilder()
                .build();

        retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                .addConverterFactory(ScalarsConverterFactory.create())
                .client(okHttpClient)
                .build();
    }
    return retrofit;
}
```